# If a different question contains the correct answer, should the question be marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, etiquette

The situation I am referring to is [this recent question on the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/157055/59407).

The situation is as follows:

> Question A is created with a certain question. Question B is an older, entirely different question, but the discussions in the comments and answers provide the solution to A.
>
> Question A has been marked as a duplicate and is now linked to Question B.

This methodology seems counter-intuitive to me. If I visit the site and happen to search for something similar to Question A, I am redirected to Question B and become confused, since I see no correlation and have no interest in plowing through the comments and answers to find the answer to my question.

What is the general consensus here? Do I stand alone in my reasoning?

Comment: Why aren't you asking this on [worldbuilding's meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/)? Unless you want a completely general answer that doesn't necessarily apply to worldbuilding at all of course.

Comment: @RobertLongson Because I was of the opinion that this situation could apply to any Stack Exchange site and is not limited to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Worldbuilding can have their own policies that would override any recommendations here.

Comment: @RobertLongson A very fair argument, though as far as my searches have concluded this is not the case.

Comment: If you asked on worldbuilding's meta, something might actually change with that question. It might get deduplicated or duplicated to something else entirely.